# chilli's yellowing on leaves only produced one fruit still flowering but dropping

Tags: diagnosis

Chillis slightly yellowing only produced one fruit when it was ripe took it off still flowing but there dropping [image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Hi Jim, can you add a picture?

Comment: hi thats me added a photo of the chilli on so you can have a look

Comment: ive tried to take as many photos as i could its under leds theres a strip led both red and blue spectrum and another led thats much further up and theres also a blue spectrum clf bulb in there too but thats not on its really on very often if it is a problem i can take it out i will also take photos of how ive set it up